# Double click to run files with own extension on Windows with own program?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Say, I have my files save in my own extension: `.example`, and I write my own program `myprogram` to read those files.

Normally, I can run it within `cmd` like:

```
cmd> myprogram myfile.example
```

Now I want my friend to run this file too, but I don't want to go tell my friend "open cmd and type this...", I just want to tell "let me install you a program, then all you have to do is double click these files"

I've try create `.bat` file, and associate that extension with `.bat` file, but after I double click on file, I couldn't get filename to run.

Please help.

Comment: That should be all you have to do. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36168008/edit) to include the code in the batch script. You're probably close.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758090(v=vs.85).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144104(v=vs.85).aspx for the documentation. Also type in a command prompt `ftype /?` and `assoc /?`.

Comment: Batch scripts aren't directly executable.  They themselves are associated with `cmd.exe`.  Do you have any better luck associating your custom extension with `cmd /c path\to\batfile`?  Is what you're calling `myprogram` the batch script, or is it a compiled and linked executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From batch file:

```
assoc .example=examplefile
ftype examplefile=c:\myprogram "%%1" %%*
```

From console:

```
assoc .example=examplefile
ftype examplefile=c:\myprogram "%1" %*
```

Try to run this once as administrator.And to open your file with the corresponding extension.

Comment: weird, I've try `set f=%1; myprogram %f%` and fail, just realize that I can do `myprogram %*` ...