# How does an OS pass a file when it is opened?

Tags: python

When you double click on a .docx file, Windows opens it in your specified program, usually Word. Same goes for any other file type. How does one make Windows open a file in a Python application? I presume it passes the file as a sys.argv, but does it pass the file contents, the path to the file, or am I way off entirely?

Comment: if you know that it is passed via `sys.argv`, why don't you write a python progam like `import sys; print(sys.argv)` and see what happens?

Comment: It depends on how you open the file.  When I open a .docx file, I get a FILE * that can be used to manipulate a stream of bytes.  Rather than "your OS opens it", perhaps you mean "the windowing system that handles the mouse click"  (it feels like you mean "double click" when you say "open").  In python, to open a file you typically use the `open` function.  If you want to relate a particular file type to an application, how to do it will depend on the windowing system you are using.

Comment: @ pasbi     I would need to get PyInstaller or an alternative. Windows can't run .py files and I am on a school computer, so my last attempt to use PyInstaller failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python` (similar to `bash`, `C` and others) passes the command line arguments.
That is, if you have a command line like
`python3 myscript.py a b c`, then `sys.argv == ['myscript.py', 'a', 'b', 'c']`.

At this point, it does not matter if `'a'`, `'b'` or `'c'` are filenames. It could be any string and even binary data.

You can, of course, interpret any argument as a filename ([there's plenty of documentation about reading files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)).

I guess you want to register your application (i.e., some python script) as the default application for a particular file type.
This is very OS-specific and [has already been discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168008/double-click-to-run-files-with-own-extension-on-windows-with-own-program).